# How to check whether the code is in NgZone?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2.

Is there a way to check whether the code now is in NgZone?

Something like this?

```
constructor(ngZone: NgZone) {}
    
foo() {
  console.log(this.ngZone.isInZoneNow);
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found out that NgZone has a static `isInAngularZone` function. So I can use

```
NgZone.isInAngularZone()
```

to check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the devtools console you won't be able to access `NgZone` easily, but you can access:

```
Zone.current.name
```

Which will either be `angular` or `<root>`

I wouldn't use this in Angular except for debugging purposes.